# Why do comments invalidate my Makefile commands?

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to add some comments to my Makefile but am seeing some odd behavior that I don't understand. The following succeeds with a `make plan-all`:

```
plan-all: \
    plan-master \
    plan-log-archive \
    plan-shared \
    plan-audit \
```

However, if I try to add comments:

```
plan-all: \
# --------------------
#  Global Accounts    |
# --------------------
    plan-master \
    plan-log-archive \
    plan-shared \
    plan-audit \
```

I get a failure:

> make: plan-master: No such file or directory

Comment: What do you think those backslashes are for? ( **P.S.** I didn't downvote.)

Comment: My guess would be to escape the newline - but according to the Makefile docs, a comment line is treated as empty so I would expect it to be inconsequential. What am I missing?

Comment: Yes, a backslash can escape a newline, but an empty line is not always inconsequential. Try replacing that comment with a single empty line, and see how the whole rule looks.

Comment: Ah, interesting! So is there a workable way to do comments at all between multiple commands?

Comment: Putting a comment between "wrapped" lines like this (the manual distinguishes *physical lines* from *logical lines,* but I don't know how widely that's used) is equivalent to putting a comment in the middle of a line; as far as I know it's impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to add comments into a logical line that uses backslashes.  It can't be done.

You can either add them before the rule, or you can use multiple rules instead of backslashes:

```
# --------------------
#  Global Accounts    |
# --------------------
plan-all: \
    plan-master \
    plan-log-archive \
    plan-shared \
    plan-audit \
```

or

```
# --------------------
#  Global Accounts    |
# --------------------
plan-all: \
    plan-master

# -------------------
#  Other Accounts    |
# -------------------
plan-all: \
    plan-log-archive \
    plan-shared \
    plan-audit \
```